# Feedback on converting signal from 3.5mm jack to ADC on STM32 Bluepill

Tags: audio, stm32, adc, diode-clamp, analog-switch

I'd like some feedback on my circuit. My goal is to convert an audio signal coming out of my laptop's 3.5mm jack (using a sin generator at max volume gives me about a ±1.5V wave) to digital using the ADC on my bluepill. From there, I plan on doing an FFT to control some neopixels. Might also implement a digital equalizer and DAC the signal out to another jack (not sure if the blue pill could handle it in real time but that's a problem for future me).

I'm using the [TS5A22364](https://www.ti.com/product/TS5A22364) to switch between the left and right channels on the jack, which saves me from having to clamp both channels. I chose the TS5A22364 because it supports a negative voltage swing. The 0.1uF capacitor is there as a bypass capacitor that the datasheet recommends. For the precision clamp, I was planning on using the [LT6015](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt6015.html) instead of the LT6106. I'm using a reference voltage of 1.65V to shift up the signal to halfway between 0 and 3.3V, the range of the blue pill's ADC. I chose RC values of 330pF and 1.5M Ohms, because I read somewhere the time constant should be at least 10 times the period of the signal going through, which should be around 0.0005 if I'm expecting up to 20kHz. Is this wrong and if so, how should I go about selecting these component values? Is there anything else I'm potentially not taking into account here?

[image: screenshot of the circuit I had in mind]

Comment: Why the clamp, it clamps instead of biasing, right? So it does not need the clamping. And the STM32 on Bluepill has multiple ADC channels so the switch is also then useless. Connecting audio channel to STM32 with minimalistic interface simply needs two resistors for biasing and a capacitor for AC coupling, double those for the second channel. Oh and the switch power supply pin has no connection to supply, it is connected to supply via capacitor.

Comment: If the 0.1 uF capacitor is intended  to be a power supply bypass capacitor, it should go between Vcc and Gnd on the chip, not in series with the 3.0V power input.  Your wiring of the input jack is wrong - pin 2 is a switch contact, and will be disconnected when the plug is inserted.